# File system that uses tags rather than folders?

Tags: tags, filesystems

My files are a mess, I try to structure them into folders with names that describe what they are in a recursive class break-down sense but later on I have trouble finding the file again when I go looking for it (the one file can possibly exist in many folders).

What file system will allow me to find my files by a combination of tags instead of using folders?

If there was such a file system, I'm not sure how OSes would cope, being so deeply dependent on the folder system. I came across [tag2find](http://www.tag2find.com/), which isn't too bad; it solves my problem with finding stuff for now but it is an application, not a file system.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/876188/89771

Comment: (as of 2013) Gmail has this system already in place with your email messages. Now to get them to implement it in Google Drive!

Comment: this question is similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393621/tagging-file-system-instead-of-directories?rq=1)

Comment: [TMSU](http://www.tmsu.org/) ([github](https://github.com/oniony/TMSU)) and [Tagsistant](http://www.tagsistant.net/) ([github](https://github.com/StrumentiResistenti/Tagsistant)) seem to be the main ones. [Dantalian](https://github.com/darkfeline/dantalian) may also be worth looking at, although I'm not sure how scalable it is.

Comment: I've thought about this, such a system could get rid of folders and even filenames altogether (not to mention the extensions nonsense). In such a way that the path, the name, and the unique identifier of a file would be just the set of tags that are applied to it. And even then, there could be more than one file with the same set of tags, why not.
The notation could be the same, e.g. `document/report/2015/finance/v2.01` in which the order of tags wouldn't matter. The great thing about this is you could just provide some tags and not all, and still get to the file[s] you want.

Comment: @Petruza I think having a unique ID tag for every file might make tag management tricky. Filenames would still be a useful property in addition to more general tags.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I am essentially using directories for tagging my files. It is very limiting because a file can only have a single parent directory. I do not care about classifying my files in folders, I am essentially trying to tag my files.

Comment: What's the problem with using an application instead of a filesystem?

Comment: In linux files can be in multiple directories using hard links (`ln` command), so it would be possible to use directories as tags and put hard links of a file in every corresponding directorie.
I don't know if that is a good idea to implement though

Comment: Windows (NTFS) supports hardlinks too, e.g. [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What you are asking for is a [Database File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Database_file_systems). I know of one experimental implementation for Linux called [DBFS](http://dbfs.sourceforge.net/). Microsoft started developing [Windows Future Storage (WinFS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winfs) - it was planned to ship with Vista but due to technical problems the project was delayed and as far as I know finally canceled. [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) is also capable of storing metadata for files but not to an extend of a full featured database file system.

The integration of such a file system into an operating system should not be that complicated for the core of the operating system - it can simply stick with the hierarchical model. The complex part is the (graphical) shell that must expose the structure and capabilities of the file system to the user.

Comment: yea, WinFS was canceled around 2006 :p. Might try out DBFS some time.

Comment: I believe they're also called *semantic* file systems, or *relational* file systems.

Comment: +1 for semantic file systems. There is a Wikipedia article on it and it contains a few links to implementations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_file_system

Answer (score 44):

Here are some file systems which I found using google.

TagFS - "Tag Semantics for Hierarchical File Systems"
paper by Stephan Bloehdorn and Max Völkel, 2006
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.60.4187

dhtfs - "Tagging based filesystem, providing dynamic directory hierarchies based on tags associated with files"
a usable implementation, last release 2007
https://github.com/mayuresh/dhtfs

Tagsistant - "A reasoning semantic filesystem for Linux and BSD"
project under active development
http://www.tagsistant.net/

Leaftag - "Tagging for the Linux desktop"
another implementation, last release 2006
http://www.chipx86.com/w/index.php/Leaftag

On integration with OSes, I don't think it should be that difficult. OSes are deeply dependent on file system hierarchy's but tag based file system can mimic directory structure. For example in a tag based file system the path `/etc/init.d` will give all the files that are tagged with exactly two tags i.e `etc` and `init.d`. For files which are tagged with other tags as well as these two tags, their extra tags can appear as directories inside `/etc/init.d`. If there is a file `a.txt` with three tags i.e `etc`, `init.d` & `asdf` then `asdf` will appear as directory inside `/etc/init.d` and full path of `a.txt` will become `/etc/init.d/asdf/a.txt`.

Comment: @clinux: Here's another recent one, [Fuse::TagLayer](https://github.com/clipland/fuse-taglayer), although it seems to be read-only.

Comment: Another: https://github.com/amoffat/supertag

Answer (score 40):

I'm the author of the Linux program [TMSU](http://www.tmsu.org/) that lets you tag files and view them in a tag-based filesystem.

Here is some example usage:

```
$ tmsu tag track.mp3 music genre=indie-rock good year=1999
$ tmsu tag melody.mp3 music
$ tmsu tag DC123.jpg photo landscape country=italy year=2014
$ tmsu files music year = 1999
./song.mp3
```

And the virtual filesystem:

```
$ mkdir mp
$ tmsu mount mp
$ ls mp
query  tags
$ ls tags
country  genre  good  landscape  photo  music  year
$ ls tags/music
genre  good  track.1.mp3  melody.2.mp3 year
```

The numbers in the filenames are identifiers which are there to keep the filenames unique. These are symbolic links back to the files' original locations.

```
$ ls tags/music/good  # you can drill down
genre  track.1.mp3  year
$ ls "query/music and good"  # this directory gets automatically created
track.1.mp3
```

It's still in active development. At time of writing (Oct 2014) 0.4.2 is available but I'll be releasing 0.5.0 soon.

Comment: Any way to use this with Windows?

Comment: @Jonathan, yes there is [an old Windows build](https://github.com/oniony/TMSU/releases/download/v0.5.0/tmsu-x86_64-0.5.0.zip) which you can try. Note that it is a bit buggy and there is no VFS support. I keep meaning to get around to doing a proper port but I want to get the core to a good state first.

Comment: Sounds awesome Paul :)

Answer (score 6):

Vista and Windows 7 support tagging of files. [See this article](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/tag-your-files-with-windows-vista/)

Comment: Unfortunately not all file types can be tagged that way.

Answer (score 5):

Try [tagfs](http://github.com/marook/tagfs). It's a fuse based user space file system. It can show tagged directories from a source directory in a tag filter view.

E.g. let's say you have a directory 'vacation india' which is tagged 'india' and 'photos' and a directory 'vacation spain' tagged 'spain' and 'photos'. You can filter all your photos by entering the path '/my_mountpoint/photos'.

Directories are tagged through a simple text file. A file named '.tag' in the directory contains the tags. Multiple tags are separated by newlines.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question while asking myself the same question about filesystem file tags. I then came across this application for Windows XP/Vista called [TaggedFrog](http://lunarfrog.com/taggedfrog/) that *may* do the trick. Haven't tried it yet, but it looks promising.

Not looking forward to going through 1000s of files though! At any rate, I'll be forced to upgrade to Win7 at some point and can try its native tagging.

Comment: I believe TaggedFrog supports newer versions of Windows too.

Answer (score 3):

I have been thinking also about a tag based file system a long time.
Has anybody thought about more radical and simple approach?
To forget folders completely (simulated folders only for compatibility reasons for programms), and put all tags directly into the file name.

(Classic File Name)_Tag1_Tag2_Tag3_.... .(File extension)

Mydocument_tag-based-file-system_tags_file-system_stackoverflow_folder_file-name_tagfs.txt

I always like to put as much information as possible in the file name. You can find everything in millions of files on every possible OS.

The only limit is the different file name length in evey OS, and it gets messy with current systems.

An advanced OS with could access a file like this: Mydocument.txt
And the Tags can be edited in the lowest level of the OS, like changing the Filename today.
If there is suddenly another Mydocument.txt it is auto renamed to Mydocument(2).txt and so on.

I know this idea is not without additional problems, not even mentioned here.....

But the Idea is about to store tags in the most basic low level possibility, that can be accessed from ALL past and future file systems. 
And what all FS have in common is the file name.

Comment: This sounds like a very crude implementation of a DBFS.

Comment: You're mixing apples and oranges.  All this does is move the hierarchical structure from the directory to the file name. Or in other words, "all in one directory" and "tags in the file names" doesn't make sense in a tag based world.  And of course you wouldn't want application programs having to deal with 10,000's of files so the OS would have to *efficiently* deliver files based on a tag spec.  So the app sends the OS the "tags" it needs to "identify the file" and... you're right back to either directories or one of the alternative file systems mentioned here.

Comment: Windows explorer has a path limit of 255 characters, which is easily reached. Otherwise the limit should be dictated by the FS limit on filenames. Pretty crude yeah, but still a nice idea. If you want to store the metadata in the file and filter it at a low level, there might be other less limited ways, such as appending or prepending data to the file, or having a "sidecar" file with the same filename but a different extension, which would contain the metadata. Another problem is that simply renaming a tag might require million of file modification operations.

Comment: Actually this idea was implemented by [TagSpaces](https://www.tagspaces.org).

Answer (score 2):

Without having tried them or seen them in the wild, there are for example

- http://nascent.freeshell.org/programming/TagFS/
- http://www.tagsistant.net/

Answer (score 2):

There is [TagsForAll](http://akslab.com) for windows. It is a file manager based on tags. Tags can have hierarchical structure. User interface is very simple but nice. Free version fully functional and save tags in database, Pro version save tags also within NTFS stream to a file.

Answer (score 2):

I found the UI design of [Elyse](http://silkwoodsoftware.com/) is wonderful. 
But it's more a static system that it can't watch folder and tag new file with a default tag automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think had (has) tagging support per se but [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Be_File_System) supports some pretty cool metadata functionality.